# Access json object using string in dot notation

Tags: javascript, json

I apologize in advance, since I realize that this should be fairly easy to solve, but for the love of me I can't make this work.

I have a json object structured like so:

```
settings:{
  prop_one:{
    desktop:{
      aaa:'',
      bbb:'',
      ccc:''
    },
    mobile:{
      aaa:'',
      bbb:'',
      ccc:''
    }
  }
}
```

next I have a function that receives the key I want to change and the parent keys in dot notation, ie.

```
myFunc('aaa', 'prop_one.desktop')
```

inside of that function what I want to do is to change the property of the given value.
since I can access json object using simple array notation in theory this would look like so:

```
myJson[prop_one][desktop][aaa] = 'some new value'
```

but I struggle here - I simply cannot figure this out, I think my brain went on holidays.
Any help how to deal with this will be hugely appreciated

```
myJson = {/* structure as bove*/}
function myFunc(parent, key)
{
//what do I do here
}
```

**EDIT:**
as pointed out to me, the object in question is JS object not JSON - obviously I took an (incorrect) shortcut here - my bad

Comment: That's not a "json object". It's an object (or a JavaScript object).

Comment: Please note the "JSON" in the example is not JSON, but is instead a JS object.

Comment: You might find lodash [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) and [set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myJson = {/* structure as above*/}
function myFunc(parent, key)
{
  const value = key.split('.').reduce((o,i)=>o[i], myJson['settings']);
  value[parent] = 'some new value';
  return myJson; 
}
```